# How to get all the parent and child node from a json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a json object which has parent and child nodes. I would like to use an higher order function which can take all the parent and child nodes from n level. Which higher order function can be taken to display the details as :

Output:

```
Parent1
Parent2
  Child1
     SubChild1
     SubChild2
  Child2
```

Parent3
      Child1
         SubChild1
         SubChild2

Json Object:

```
[{children:[], id:35, map_data:{தாலூகா:"மானாமதுரை"}, name:"Matae1"},
{children:[], id:36, map_data:{தாலூகா:"மானாமதுரை"}, name:"Matae2"},
{children:[{children:[], id:39, map_data:{தாலூகா:"மானாமதுரை"}, name:"Child1"}], id:36, map_data:{தாலூகா:"மானாமதுரை"}, name:"Matae3"}]
```

Structure is like:

[image]

Comment: How would you like the output of the function ?

Answer (score 0):

When you need to traverse an arbitrarily you can use a simple recursive strategy: get the thing you want from the first level, like `name` and then pass the children to the same function. You can pass an array and level in with the function for convenience to keep track of the items and which level you are in at the moment.

For example (I've simplified your object to make it clearer):

```js
let obj = [{
    children: [],
    name: "parent 1"
  },
  {
    children: [{
        children: [{
          children: [],
          name: "grandchild 1"
        }, ],
        name: "child 1"
      },
      {
        children: [],
        name: "child 2"
      },
    ],
    name: "parent 2"
  },
  {
    children: [],
    name: "parent 3"
  },
]

function getChildren(arr, output = [], level = 0) {
  arr.forEach(item => {
    output.push(" ".repeat(level * 2) + item.name)
    getChildren(item.children, output, level + 1)
  })
  return output
}
let out = getChildren(obj)
console.log(out.join('\n'))
```